# Simple C program occasionally hangs on launch

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I'm learning C and currently working with pointers, I wrote a function to call `calloc()` with an argument to something outside of that function.  It compiles fine, I turned on every GCC warning option I could find and get nothing except unused `argc` and `argv`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int foo;
} thing_t;

static void init_thing( thing_t **t );

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    thing_t *thing = NULL;
    init_thing( &thing );
    assert( thing );
    return 0;
}

static void init_thing( thing_t **t ) {
    *t = calloc( 1, sizeof( thing_t ) );
    assert( t );
}
```

After compiling, it seems to run normally a few times but will eventually hang when starting:

```
C:\work>a.exe

C:\work>a.exe

C:\work>a.exe
(hangs)
```

I tried to figure out what was wrong using gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\work/a.exe
[New Thread 17644.0x308c]
[New Thread 17644.0x1084]
[Inferior 1 (process 17644) exited normally]
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\work/a.exe
[New Thread 17276.0x4250]
[New Thread 17276.0x30c]
[Inferior 1 (process 17276) exited normally]
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\work/a.exe
[New Thread 8752.0x4c54]
[New Thread 8752.0x62c]
[Inferior 1 (process 8752) exited normally]
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\work/a.exe
[New Thread 20456.0x4114]
[New Thread 20456.0x2ee8]
(hangs)
```

Pressing CTRL+C here endlessly prints:

```
[New Thread 20456.0x2b10]
[New Thread 20456.0x176c]
[New Thread 20456.0x51f8]
[New Thread 20456.0x12a0]
[New Thread 20456.0x2cf8]
[New Thread 20456.0x76c]
...
```

I tried setting breakpoints at `main()` and `init_thing()` but can't reproduce the hang when doing this.  I think I'm mixing something up with `*`, `**`, `&` but I'm not sure how to find out where the problem is.

Using GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: There is no way to reproduce the behavior you describe with *just* the code you posted. And you are missing a  `free(thing)`, also do not use `calloc()` unless you *REALLY* want to initialize to `0`.

Comment: Your program looks reasonable - I've run it a few thousand times, and it hasn't hung so far. I don't see a reason why it could, either. Very mysterious.

Comment: Sidenote: `assert( t );` - I guess you meant `*t`.

Comment: Try disabling your Antivirus software.

Comment: `init_thing`  should *return* a result (a pointer), then better name it `make_thing` or `create_thing`

Comment: I should have included how I was compiling as well or tried without the mass of warning arguments I found, `-pg` was mixed in with them and seems to have been the cause for whatever reason.  Thanks for the other corrections.